Aside from the Task Scheduler, how can tasks automatically fire on a fresh Windows Server 2019 machine?
I have a Windows Server 2019 machine. It is pretty much an empty box. My company has installed a handful of things on it, but I am convinced that I have checked it all. Mysteriously, the CPU goes wild at a particular time every week. I have checked the Task Scheduler, but it doesn't have anything running at that particular time.
Assuming that we can treat this as a fresh install of Windows Server 2019, how can something run at the same time every week if it isn't in the Task Scheduler? What features allow task scheduling, other than the Task Scheduler?

Is it on a network? If so, it could be requests from outside; check connection logs. Also, look at MS own Autoruns.
